# How to filter a MongoDB/Mongoose query based upon referenced subdocuments values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I am currently working on cloning some app concepts (for learning purposes) and I have built a basic social media app that has users, posts, & allows users to block users if they don't want to share data. But my question is, can I use referenced documents values/data (a populated user's array of blocked users) to filter out the parent document (the post)? Hope this makes sense.

So far, here are the schemas (trimmed down of course):

```
// User Schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;    
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please provide an email"],
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 8
    },
    blockedUsers: {
        type: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }]
    }
});

// Post Schema
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    dateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        maxlength: 1200
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Then my query I have so far which only filters out the subdocument and in my tests is returning a `null` author to my post which is not exactly the functionality I was hoping for. To clarify, it still returns the right post that was queried, but it does not populate the 'author' field and instead sets the author field to `null`.

```
router.get('/p/:postID', catchAsyncErr(async (req, res, next) => {
    // Find post and make sure the user requesting the post is not blocked by the author
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.postID).populate({
        path: 'author',
        select: 'blockedUsers',
        match: {
            blockedUsers: {
                $ne: req.user.id // The user ID stored in the JSON Web token
            }
        }
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Success',
        statusCode: 200,
        message: `Post "${req.params.postID}" found`,
        data: post
    })
}));
```

I tried using aggregation and honestly am still trying to fully wrap my head around the `$lookup` concept. But I have a strange feeling that that should be where I am testing more...

Basically, I am really trying to hide the post and return a 404 if the author (user) has the requesting user on the 'blockedUsers' list. I understand I can do this using regular if/else statements but I was really hoping to be able to do this inside a query. Further more, I want to be able to implement this same concept on a users home feed if you will. If they are blocked by a user, the user who blocked them would not have their post show up in their feed.

Thank you for any of your insights on this!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregation pipeline` to do that. You need `$lookup` for join (populate) author and `$match` for filter your user.

`$match` is very similar to your first parameter in `find()`.

`$lookup` is similar to `join` in SQL if you familiar with.

For setting up `$lookup` you need four parameters.

`from`: Which is your destination collection (Here is `users`)
`localField`: Which your foreign key field name (Here `author`)
`foreignField`: Which is destination collection field (Here `_id`)
`as`: Name after join (Here I use `author`)

Here is the snippet:

```js
const post = Post.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    _id: req.params.postID
  }
}, 
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    localField: 'author',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'author'
  }
}])
```

Then your `post.author.blockedUsers` should work fine.

If you want to retrieve specific blockedUsers you can use aggregation like this:

```js
const post = Post.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    _id: req.params.postID
  }
}, 
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    'let': {authorId: "$author"},
    pipeline: [{
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [{
            $eq: ['$_id', '$$authorId']
          }, {
            $ne: ['$blockedUsers', req.user.id]
          }]
        }
      }
    }
    as: 'author'
  }
}])
```

Comment: This is an incredible start and logically it makes complete sense but for some reason, when I used the second snippet you presented, it is retrieving the right post but still returning the post even if the requesting user is blocked. But I also noticed that the populated author details is returning and array. Could this affect reading if a user is blocked?

Comment: Ok, so I just tested changing matching the `$_id` with another specified ID that doesn't match the original authors and it has similar results as my approach above where it just isn't returning an author. By doing this is there a way to make the parent post not return?